# I can't login with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, spring-boot

I'm writing a Flutter web project with a Spring boot backend and am really battling with getting the authentication stuff to work.

When I lose insomnia its work but with flutter I get this error :

[image]
[image]

How can I solve this?

this is my code :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:basic_utils/basic_utils.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:cryptoo/main.dart';
import 'package:cryptoo/screens/signup.dart';
import 'package:cryptoo/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/http.dart';
class SignInScreen extends StatefulWidget {   
  static const kBackgroundColor = Colors.white;
  static const kPrimaryColor = Colors.amber;
  @override
  State<SignInScreen> createState() => _SignInScreenState();
}
class _SignInScreenState extends State<SignInScreen> {
  final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  User user = User("", "");
  String api = "192.168.1.105";
  Future save() async {
    String url = "http://" + api + ":8011/users/login";
    String username = user.username;
    String password = user.password;
    Map<String, String> headers = {"Accept": "application/json"};
    var res = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),    `problem here .......
        headers: headers,
        body: jsonEncode({'username': 'Yosry1', 'password': 'Hamdi24963'}));
    print(res.statusCode);
    /*print(user.username);
    print(user.password);*/
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      await Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
      print("connected");
    }
  }
  var size, height, width;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    height = size.height;
    width = size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _formkey,
        child: Container(
          width: width,
          height: height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xff1f2630),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.alternate_email,
                    color: SignInScreen.kPrimaryColor,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    width: width * 0.8,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: TextEditingController(text: user.username),
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        user.username = val;
                      },
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Username is Empty';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        hintText: "Username",
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.lock,
                    color: SignInScreen.kPrimaryColor,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    width: width * 0.8,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: TextEditingController(text: user.password),
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        user.password = val;
                      },
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Password is Empty';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        hintText: "Password",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => SignUpScreen(),
                      ));
                },
                child: Text("SingUp"),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 5),
              Container(
                width: width * 0.7,
                height: 50,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    /* Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => HomeScreen();*/
                    //if (_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {}
                    save();
                  },
                  child: Text("SignIn"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You have posted _pictures_ of _text_.  Just post the text!

Comment: Is your request working on postman or such? Can you try adding "Content-type": "application/json" in the header instead of "Accept": "application/json"